# JPA good practices mapping table

Tags: java, jpa

Im trying to apply the best practices to my JPA mapping table but i have a question about it, this is my table map:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TW_TABLE")
public class TwTable {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "N_ID")
   private Long nId;

   @Column(name = "N_IDCATALOGE")
   private Long nIdCataloge;

   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "N_IDCATALOGE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private TcCataloge tcCataloge;

}
```

this is my entity i have more columns and i have my getters and setters but i dont need them here, my questions is about the column N_IDCATALOGE, some querys only need the ID of the cataloge but some others will need the complete entity of tcCataloge, is it a good practice have both on the entity or should i delete the single column nIdCataloge and use the object to get the ID (on some cases i will only need the ID not the full object)?